# Angular filter unique array of object

Tags: angular, typescript, object, mapping

i want to filter unique array of objects. my initial array would be

```
var initialObjArray=[ {lat:10,lon:20},{lat :10,lon:30} ,{lat :10,lon:20}];
```

my result array would be

```
var initialObjArray=[ {lat:10,lon:20},{lat :10,lon:30}];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Comment: i want to filter from array of object not only  array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
var result =  []
initialObjArray.forEach(item => {
  let count = result.filter(x => x.lat == item.lat && x.lon == item.lon).length

  if(count == 0) {
    result.push(item)
  }
})
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oqxyqk?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: can you tell me the complexity of this process?

Comment: Complexity as in.. can you explain

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to filter duplicate objects.

```js
var initialObjArray = [{ lat:10, lon:20 }, { lat :10, lon:30 }, { lat :10, lon:20 }];

var unique = initialObjArray.filter((value, index, arr) => {
  return index === arr.findIndex(obj => obj.lat === value.lat && obj.lon === value.lon);
});

console.log(unique);
```